# Accessibility API - Setting keyboard focus to a specific element

Tags: cocoa, accessibility, macos-carbon, core-foundation

Using the accessibility API, I am drilling down through a series of elements and finding a specific AXUIElementRef I am interested in (all in an external application).  How do I check if this element currently has keyboard focus?  And if not, how do I set it?

Something similar to using AXUIElementSetAttributeValue to set the kAXMainAttribute to true (this works for a window - thanks Peter!).

PS - I have tried kAXFocusedAttribute, doesn't seem to do the job.  Maybe it's read only?

Answer (score 1):

> PS - I have tried kAXFocusedAttribute, doesn't seem to do the job. Maybe it's read only?

Quite the opposite. Read the header:

> Writable? Yes, for any focusable element. No in all other cases.

Make sure you've activated the application (by setting its `kAXFrontmostAttribute` to true) and made the window key (by setting its `kAXFocusedAttribute` to true) before you give a control in the window focus (by setting *its* `kAXFocusedAttribute` to true).

Comment: I'm getting an error code - 25205 - back from the set method.  No idea where to find out what this could be - I don't even know what language I'm using at this point...

Presumably if there is a hierarchy of elements I need to focus on each of them in turn down to the one I want?  Or once i'm in the app and window, is that enough?

Comment: The errors are named in AXError.h. And you are using C (possibly within Objective-C).